# How to apply two numbered heading style in the same line in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2019

I have created numbered heading styles in word and they work fine, as shown in "1". But sometime I have to format as shown in "2". How can I have two heading styles in one line?

Heading styles work fine when on separate lines.
[image: heading styles are working fine in separate line]

How can I have two heading style in one line like this?
[image: How to have two heading style in one line?]

Comment: Are you able to introduce a line break between styles and the delete the line break later

Comment: A *heading* style applies to a whole paragraph, by definition. The best you could would be to select text and set its style manually.

Comment: Do you need to have both in the same document?

Comment: yes I need them both in the same document.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying hard not to question why you would want such an inconsistent and illogical numbering structure.

But what you might want look into is a style separator. To make use of a style separator, you have to

1. Insert two paragraphs (e.g. first paragraph = heading text, second paragraph = other text)
2. Click at the end of the first paragraph
3. Hit CTRL + ALT + ENTER

This will insert a style separator at the end of the first paragraph and shift the second paragraph to the cursor position. You can not click into the heading (the part before the style separator) and apply a heading style to it and then you can click into the part after the style separator and apply and type of different style to it.
Note however, that if you try to apply a list numbering to the second part (after the style separator), Word won't insert an additional number. So, for this first line you'd have to insert the number manually.

Comment: I am able to combine numbered Headings 1 and Heading 2 with the style separator but not further. Use of the SEQ field or a ListNum field could also be considered. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/field-codes-seq-sequence-field-062a387b-dfc9-4ef8-8235-29ee113d59be  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/field-codes-listnum-field-557541b1-abb2-4959-a9f2-401639c8ff82

Comment: ListNum field is working. Thanks Charles Kenyon